# Cordova: Restict API access of external javaScript, sandbox exernal JS

Tags: javascript, cordova, security, sandbox

**background:**
I'm new to Cordova and we are using it to create a small iOS and Android app that includes google maps functionality.

My initial approach was to just use the google maps API, just like on a website (I know that there is a specific cordova plugin for that...), but I am worried about remote code execution.

**question:**
Let's say I include an external script into my app like so: `<script src="http://example.com/script.js">` Is there a way to sandbox this origin/script so that it cannot use any of the cordova APIs allowing it to reach beyond what would be the sandbox of the browser?

I don't mind some malicious code to fire a few `alert('buy GME!')` messages, but I don't want it to syphon user data from the phone...

Comment: As long as `cordova.exec()` from `cordova.js` is accessible I don't think is possible.

Comment: You can use content security policy